# instead of {% block content %} I'm using {% block sub-header%} under navbar, isnt this valid?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hello I want to have different sub header under navbar for different pages. so I used `{% block %}` I learnt. but this time it's not showing anything, no content no error. am I doing it wrong?

Inside navbar.html

```
<nav>
    <div id="bottom header" style="background:yellow;">
    {% block sub-header %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
</nav>
```

then inside base.html I have

```
extends navbar.html
```

then inside index.html I have

```
extends base.html

{% block sub-header %}
<p>hello yall</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think the django template engine only accepts alphanumeric characters and _ for the block tag. So either use, `subheader` or `sub_header`.

Comment: @RodXavier even by changing to subheader that it doesn't work...

Comment: Why are you extending navbar.html in base.html? I think you should use include.

Comment: oh yeah I meant to use include

Comment: Can you please post all of your template files concerning this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105073/discussion-between-winixxee-and-rod-xavier).

Comment: @RodXavier hi sorry but can I show you the files in the discussion chat??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not process blocks in included files.

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of "render
>   this subtemplate and include the HTML", not as "parse this subtemplate
>   and include its contents as if it were part of the parent". This means
>   that there is no shared state between included templates -- each
>   include is a completely independent rendering process.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include) for more information.

The problem is that `{% block sub_header %}` is inside `navbar.html`, which is an included template on `base.html`. One way to get around this restriction is to extract parts of your nav into the base:

```
<!-- base.html -->
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        {% block sub_header %}{% endblock %}
    </nav>
    <!-- other HTML here -->
</body>
```

Then your templates which extend `base.html` can use `{%block sub_header %}`

```
<!-- my-template.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block sub_header %}
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```